# Factoring the roots of function in general

Tags: calculus, factoring

When finding derivative of $x^2$ or $x^3$. It always show that the infinitesimal small quantity h is canceled. Further more, special function like $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can be computed  and derivative of $\vert x-a \vert$ or $x \sin \frac {1}{x-a}$ at $a$ do not exist only because of $\lim_{x\to a+} \neq \lim_{x \to a-}$ and discontinuous at $a$. So the derivative of f(x) at a must cancel the infinitesimal small quantity h otherwise $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ do not make sense. Then in general if $G(\alpha)=0$ does it implies that $G(x)=(x-\alpha)h(x)$ for some $h(x)$?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your posting, and understanding the question that you are asking.  If some other MathSE reviewer steps up, fine.  If not, please re-word your posting to try to make it crystal clear, what you are saying, preferably with 1 or 2 explanatory examples.   When done, you can flag me with an @user2661923 comment ...see next comment

Comment: For example, what are you saying here: "When finding derivative of $x^2$ or $x^3$. It always show that the infinitesimal small quantity h is canceled. Further more, special function like $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can be computed  and derivative of $\vert x-a \vert$ or $x \sin \frac {1}{x-a}$ at $a$ do not exist only because of $\lim_{x\to a+} \neq \lim_{x \to a-}$ and discontinuous at $a$."

Comment: @user2661923  Those example when I calculate derivative of polynomial function and rational function by definition. The infinitesimal small quantity h always be canceled, the example which the derivative does not exist at a are those I posted. I r do not know how to calculate derivative of sin(x) and cos(x) but I know it exist. Then my conclusion that f(x)-f(a) which have root x=a must cancel the x-a term in $lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Then generalize  if function G(x) has $\alpha$ as root then it can be written as G(x)=(x-$\alpha$)*H(x) for some H(x)

Comment: I am sorry.  I still don't understand what you are saying or what you are asking.  Perhaps it is my limited comprehension.  Perhaps someone else will step up.  If not, perhaps you could try to be more clear, with several illustrative examples, to clarify what you are saying, and what you are asking.

Comment: @user2661923 I mean if we calculate the derivative of f(x) then the term "f(x)-f(a)" must eliminate the term "x-a" in order to $ lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exist if f is polynomial we often call (f(x)-f(a)) is divisible by (x-a). If f(x)= sin (x) I do not know how (sin(x)-sin(a)) is "divisible" by (x-a) but its derivative exist and equal to cos(x). Then I treat g(x)=f(x)-f(a) as a function , g(a)=0 and g(a) is "divisible" by (x-a). So I wonder if any function G(x) has a root $\alpha$ does it implies that G(x) is "divisible" by (x-$\alpha$) and can be written as G(x)=(x-$\alpha$)H(x)

Comment: If $~f(x) = \sin(x),~$ then you can use the **alternative definition** that $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$  Then, you have that $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(h) + \sin(h) \cos(x) - \sin(x)}{h}.$$  As $~h \to 0,~$ this goes to  $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(x) + \sin(h)\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{h}.$$ This equals $$\cos(x) \times \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} = \cos(x).$$

Comment: Note:  In Real Analysis, the sine and cosine function are defined somewhat differently than in Analytical Geometry or Trigonometry.  In Real Analysis, the sine and cosine are functions whose domain is Real Numbers, rather than angles.  These Real Numbers represent arc lengths with respect to the unit circle (of radius = 1). ...see next comment

Comment: In the Real Analysis redefinition of the sine and cosine functions, there are certain axioms which these functions are required to satisfy.  As a consequence of these axioms, you have that $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} = 1$$ and $$\sin(r+s) = \sin(r)\cos(s) + \sin(s)\cos(r).$$

Comment: @user2661923  What I am asking for is if G(x) has $\alpha$ as root does it mean we can factor it out as G(x)= (x-$\alpha$)H(x)? For example $sin(x)=H(x)*x*(x-\pi)*(x+\pi)*(x-2\pi)*(x+2\pi)...$ or $e^x -1 =x*H(x)$. I observed that when I calculate the derivative, the (f(x)-f(a)) term must eliminate the (x-a) term.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you are focusing on the derivative of either the sine or cosine functions, you want to use **my alternative** definition of the derivative, **not your definition**.  Beyond that, there is a theorem in Algebra that says that if $~f(x)~$ is a **polynomial of degree** $~n > 1,~$ and $~\alpha~$ is a root of the equation $~f(x) = 0,~$ then there **does exist** a polynomial $~g(x)~$ of degree $~(n-1)~$ such that $~f(x) = (x-a) \times g(x).$

Comment: Can we do factor (x-a) for any function f(x) if a is root of f(x)? Are there any theorem about it? @user2661923

Comment: Not that I know of.  The theorem only applies to functions $~f(x)~$ that are polynomials.  There may be some other theorems that are similar, that I have never heard of.  The only such theorem that I know about only applies when $~f(x)~$ is a polynomial.